# Почему игры - подковерные?

Tags: фразеология

О каких-то тайных делах, интригах говорят, что это подковерные игры. А почему так? При чем тут ковер и во что там можно играть?)))

Answer (score 3):

Из следующего ниже выражения о политической борьбе.

> Схватка бульдогов под ковром — ничего не видно, только время от времени вываливается загрызенный насмерть бульдог.

Фразу приписывают Черчилю, но автором её судя по всему является поляк Стефан Киселевский.

Answer (score 0):

логически: на ковре, значит на виду, прозрачно))) под ковром- скрытно, тайком...